# Barcode Scanning is there API for getting product details etc?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am in java Android ZXing library, and I wanted to get product details on that.  Where can I go with API to get product details.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Back when I was looking for this, I couldnt find anything. Unless things have changed, your best bet is to grab the barcode, and scrape Google or Amazon for the details. In fact, Amazon *might* have an API in their dev stuff, but last I checked their product search wasnt compatible with Android yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for media information, like movies or books, Hooked In Motion has one: http://www.hookedinmotion.com/?page_id=246